# How can I see the effect of sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, preprocessor, sympy

If I have a moderate number of basic features and am generating from them a moderate order of polynomial features, it can get kind of confusing to know which column of the features array `preprocess_XX` corresponds to which transformation of the basic features.

I used to do something like the following, with an older version of sklearn (maybe 0.14?):

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import Symbol
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
poly = PolynomialFeatures(4)
x1 = Symbol('x1')
x2 = Symbol('x2')
x3 = Symbol('x3')
XX = np.random.rand(1000, 3)  # replace with the actual data array
preprocess_symXX = poly.fit_transform([x1, x2, x3])
preprocess_XX = poly.fit_transform(XX)
print preprocess_symXX
```

This was awesome.  It would produce output like `[1, x1, x2, x3, x1**2, ... ]`, which would let me know what polynomial functions my columns of `preprocess_XX` actually came from.

But now when I do this, it complains `TypeError: can't convert expression to float`.  This exception is raised because of a function in `sklearn.utils.validation` called `check_array()`, which attempts to cast the input to `poly.fit_transform()` to `dtype=float`.

Do you have a recommendation for how to see what polynomial of the basic features corresponds to which column in the output of `fit_transform()?`, now that `sympy` no longer seems to work with `fit_transform`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use poly.powers_ to get the powers. Then you can transform it into something human readable like this:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

X = np.random.rand(1000, 3)

poly = PolynomialFeatures(4)
Y = poly.fit_transform(X)

features = ['X1','X2','X3']

print(poly.powers_)

for entry in poly.powers_:
    newFeature = []
    for feat, coef in zip(features, entry):
        if coef > 0:
            newFeature.append(feat+'**'+str(coef))
    if not newFeature:
        print(1) # If all powers are 0
    else:
        print(' + '.join(newFeature))
```

which prints (after printing poly.powers_):

```
1
X1**1
X2**1
X3**1
X1**2
X1**1 + X2**1
X1**1 + X3**1
X2**2
X2**1 + X3**1
X3**2
X1**3
X1**2 + X2**1
X1**2 + X3**1
X1**1 + X2**2
X1**1 + X2**1 + X3**1
X1**1 + X3**2
X2**3
X2**2 + X3**1
X2**1 + X3**2
X3**3
X1**4
X1**3 + X2**1
X1**3 + X3**1
X1**2 + X2**2
X1**2 + X2**1 + X3**1
X1**2 + X3**2
X1**1 + X2**3
X1**1 + X2**2 + X3**1
X1**1 + X2**1 + X3**2
X1**1 + X3**3
X2**4
X2**3 + X3**1
X2**2 + X3**2
X2**1 + X3**3
X3**4
```